# collect 2: error: ld returned 1 exit status when compling

Tags: compiling, make, c, exit-status

I'm trying to install [xschem](https://github.com/StefanSchippers/xschem) on a remote computer (centos 7).
I ran ./configure and it was successful (i.e. no missing packages)

However when I'm trying to run make in the same directory I get:

```
/cs/local/bin/ld: main.o: in function `main':
main.c:(.text.startup+0x14f): undefined reference to `Tcl_MainEx'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Makefile:18: xschem] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/local/data0/Xschem/xschem/src'
make: *** [Makefile:2: all] Error 2
```

please note: I ran ./configure --prefix=/local/data0//Xschem/xschem/

and the contents of the main.c is:

```
#include "xschem.h"
#ifdef __unix__
#include <sys/wait.h>
#endif
#include <locale.h>

static void sig_handler(int s){
  char emergency_prefix[PATH_MAX];
  const char *emergency_dir;


  if(s==SIGINT) {
    fprintf(errfp, "Use 'exit' to close the program\n");
    return;
  }

  if(xctx->undo_type == 0 ) { /* on disk undo */
    my_snprintf(emergency_prefix, S(emergency_prefix), "xschem_emergencysave_%s_",
             skip_dir(xctx->sch[xctx->currsch]));
    if( !(emergency_dir = create_tmpdir(emergency_prefix)) ) {
      fprintf(errfp, "xinit(): problems creating emergency save dir\n");
      tcleval("exit");
    }
  
    if(rename(xctx->undo_dirname, emergency_dir)) {
      fprintf(errfp, "rename dir %s to %s failed\n", xctx->undo_dirname, emergency_dir);
    }
    fprintf(errfp, "EMERGENCY SAVE DIR: %s\n", emergency_dir);
  }




  fprintf(errfp, "\nFATAL: signal %d\n", s);
  fprintf(errfp, "while editing: %s\n", skip_dir(xctx->sch[xctx->currsch]));
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

#if 0
static void child_handler(int signum)
{
    /* fprintf(errfp, "SIGCHLD received\n"); */
#ifdef __unix__
    wait(NULL);
#endif
}
#endif

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int i;
  my_strdup(45, &xschem_executable, argv[0]);
  signal(SIGINT, sig_handler);
  signal(SIGSEGV, sig_handler);
  signal(SIGILL, sig_handler);
  signal(SIGTERM, sig_handler);
  signal(SIGFPE, sig_handler);
  /* signal(SIGCHLD, child_handler); */  /* avoid zombies 20180925 --> conflicts with tcl exec */

  errfp=stderr;
  /* 20181013 check for empty or non existing DISPLAY *before* calling Tk_Main or Tcl_Main */
#ifdef __unix__
  if(!getenv("DISPLAY") || !getenv("DISPLAY")[0]) has_x=0;
#endif
  argc = process_options(argc, argv);
  if(debug_var>=1 && !has_x)
    fprintf(errfp, "main(): no DISPLAY set, assuming no X available\n");
  /* if detach is 1 no interactive command shell is created ...
   * using detach if no windowing exists (has_x == 0) is non sense so do nothing
   */



  cli_opt_argc = argc;
  cli_opt_argv = my_malloc(291, cli_opt_argc * sizeof(char *));
  for(i = 0; i < cli_opt_argc; i++) {
    cli_opt_argv[i] = NULL;
    my_strdup(374, &cli_opt_argv[i], argv[i]);
  }



  if(detach && has_x) {
    fclose(stdin);
    Tcl_FindExecutable(argv[0]); /* tcl stores executable name for its internal usage */
    interp = Tcl_CreateInterp(); /* create the tcl interpreter */
    Tcl_AppInit(interp); /* execute our init function */
    Tk_MainLoop(); /* ok, now all done go into the event loop */
  } else { /* ... else start tcl or tk main loop and enter interactive mode (tcl shell) */
    if(has_x) Tk_Main(1, argv, Tcl_AppInit);
    else     Tcl_Main(1, argv, Tcl_AppInit);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Could you suspect where is the problem?
thanks in advance

Comment: The error indicates that the linker could not find the TCL library. How was TCL installed on the system?